# Why doesn't this work?: decoding json into php array

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
$json = file_get_contents('outputsjson.php');
```

The file encodes an array then just echoes it as this (and `echo $json` outputs this):

```
{"theList":{"1":{"name":"DSC04156.JPG","title":"DSC04156.JPG","width":3264},"2":{"name":"DSC04157.JPG","title":"DSC04157.JPG","width":3264},"3":{"name":"DSC04158.JPG","title":"DSC04158.JPG","width":3264},"4":{"name":"DSC04159.JPG","title":"DSC04159.JPG","width":3264}}}
```

Now I'm trying to decode it from another page like this:

```
$myarray = json_decode($json, true);

print_r($myarray);
```

This outputs nothing, no errors, nothing!

Comment: do you have errors turn off in the php.ini?

Comment: How did you form this json?! by hand I suppose? your double quotes are not escaped!

Comment: Not that this will help you any, but why are you telling json_decode to convert the object into an associative array?

Comment: have you tried turning up error reporting to `E_STRICT` or something?

Comment: @Adrian, because it's in plain text form and I can use it on the other page without putting it in an array.

Comment: make sure `$json` contains the contents, it might be that `file_get_contents()` isnt working

Comment: @Chad, what do you get if you do `echo $json`?

Comment: @Neal, the above JSON string.

Comment: @Chad, so there is no reason why that shouldnt work. try making it so u can see all of the errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead (you are mixing `"` and `'` [single quotes instead of double quotes on the string]):

```
$json = '{"theList":{"1":{"name":"DSC04156.JPG","title":"DSC04156.JPG","width":3264},"2":{"name":"DSC04157.JPG","title":"DSC04157.JPG","width":3264},"3":{"name":"DSC04158.JPG","title":"DSC04158.JPG","width":3264},"4":{"name":"DSC04159.JPG","title":"DSC04159.JPG","width":3264}}} ';

$myarray = json_decode($json, true);

print_r($myarray);
```

And your result:

```
Array
(
    [theList] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => DSC04156.JPG
                    [title] => DSC04156.JPG
                    [width] => 3264
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => DSC04157.JPG
                    [title] => DSC04157.JPG
                    [width] => 3264
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => DSC04158.JPG
                    [title] => DSC04158.JPG
                    [width] => 3264
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [name] => DSC04159.JPG
                    [title] => DSC04159.JPG
                    [width] => 3264
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: sorry, I didn't explain clearly enought, I've updated the question.

Comment: SOLVED. What happened was I had a <div> tag (just the tag, no content) before the json in the file that echoes the json. Oddly though it did not show up in the value of file_get_contents(); Very odd.

Comment: lol well it wouldnt show unless u were not in a browser :-) glad you solved it

Comment: yeah, that was weird. quite an obvious mistake, make sure you view-source when you do an echo/print, or do a `htmlspecialchars($json)` on the thing to print..

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the json string in single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
$json = '{"theList":{"1":{"name":"DSC04156.JPG","title":"DSC04156.JPG","width":3264},"2":{"name":"DSC04157.JPG","title":"DSC04157.JPG","width":3264},"3":{"name":"DSC04158.JPG","title":"DSC04158.JPG","width":3264},"4":{"name":"DSC04159.JPG","title":"DSC04159.JPG","width":3264}}}';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had no problems executing the following code:

```
$json = '{"theList":{"1":{"name":"DSC04156.JPG","title":"DSC04156.JPG","width":3264},"2":{"name":"DSC04157.JPG","title":"DSC04157.JPG","width":3264},"3":{"name":"DSC04158.JPG","title":"DSC04158.JPG","width":3264},"4":{"name":"DSC04159.JPG","title":"DSC04159.JPG","width":3264}}}';
$myarray = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($myarray);
```

My guess would be that the file you are trying to read from does not exist.  Remember that, if you are using Linux, file names are case-sensitive.  Use the [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/file_exists) function to check this:

`var_dump(file_exists('outputsjson.php'));`